# How to observe c++ destructor destroys basic data types?

Tags: c++, destructor

I have two classes one is main and other is Test,  for the Test class, I have Test.cpp and Test.h

```
//-----Test.h--------//
#pragma once
class Test
{
private:
    int num;
public:
    Test(void);
    Test(int n);
    ~Test(void);
};



//------Test.cpp------//

#include "Test.h"

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


Test::Test(void)
{
}

Test::Test(int n)
{
    num = n;
}

Test::~Test(void)
{
    cout << "Deleted" << endl;
    cout << "num = " << num << endl ;
}


//---------main.cpp--------------//


#include "Test.h"

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Test t1 = Test(5);
    return 0;
}
```

The output which I have expected is

**Deleted**

**num = 0**

But Real Output is

**Deleted**

**num = 5**

Why this occurs, why destructor, dint free the memory
or dint delete the basic data type, How can I delete the variable,
Using what method I can observe basic datatype getting deleted?

Comment: You cannot observe destruction of fundamental types from within your program. An object is either alive or dead. If you access a dead object, the behaviour is undefined. You are not guaranteed to get a zero or any other value back. You may get a zero, you may get a random value, you may get an explosion in your face. In your example, `num` is alive until the end of the destructor. And please stop using `_tmain` and `TCHAR`, these are remnants of Windows 95, nobody should need them in 2020.

Comment: You have the wrong expectation. When a desturctor's body is executed, the members are still very much alive. It'd be very bad if they weren't. When your destructor is meant to close a database connection, the member it uses for the DB handle must still be valid inside the body of the destructor.

Comment: Basic data types are not destroyed. Your question is founded on a false assumption.

Comment: Can you point to any ressource that leads you to expect such behaviour? If so, we may be able to clear up some misconceptions you seem to have.

Comment: Note that `std::cout << "Deleted" << endl;` in a destructor makes a misleading statement. It should be `std::cout << "Destroyed" << endl;`. When an auto object goes out of scope it gets destroyed; when a pointer created by `new T` is passed to `delete ptr;` it gets deleted, and the object that it points to gets destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Destruction of an object does not mean setting values to zero. That would be unnecessary work. Rather, all that is required is that resources be released. Bits are typically left as-is (representing `5` in your example) unless there is a compelling reason to do otherwise.

Furthermore, members are destroyed after the class. In your example, first `~Test()` is run to destroy `t1`, then `t1.num` would be destroyed. The destructor of `Test` cannot view the destruction of `Test::num`.

Answer (score 0):

> why destructor, dint free the memory or dint delete the basic data type

You did not have any memory allocated in the heap, so there is no need to free anything.

All you have is a basic type `int` which does not need any memory deallocation.

If instead you had some pointer member variable:

```
private:
    int* num;
```

and you allocated it somewhere in your constructor: `new int(6);` then sure you must deallocate/free it inside your destructor.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, probably a shared-pointer may help, which automatically is destroyed just after the destructor:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> num;
```

But it has to be constructed, in the constructor you need:

```
Test::Test(int n)
: num(std::make_shared<int>(n)
{
    // *n == 100
}
```

To see if the data is deleted use **Valgrind**.